# rails has many association get latest record based on enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, has-many

I have a model as:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patient_statuses
end
```

Another model as:

```
class PatientStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient

  enum status: [:registered, :pending, :check_up, :admitted, :discharged]
end
```

Now, I want to get all the `Patient` whose last status is `admitted`

Comment: How will you order the status? By `created_at`?

Comment: yes, it will be order by `created_at`

Answer (score 1):

I think could do something like this:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  ... 
  has_one  :current_status, -> 
    { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }, class_name: 'PatientStatus'

  ...
  def self.admitted
    includes(:current_status).where(
      patient_statuses: { status: 'admitted' }).references(:current_status)
  end
end
```

You would call this scope method like this:

```
Patient.admitted
```

You could also create a scope that accepts an argument and get Patients based on any status:

```
def self.with_status(status)
  includes(:current_status).where(
    patient_statuses: { status: status }).references(:current_status)
end

Patient.with_status('admitted')
```

Note that this code is provided as an example and might require some tweaking because of your enum attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
ids = PatientStatus.group('user_id', 'id').having('created_at = MAX(created_at)').where(status: :admitted).map(&:user_id).uniq
patients = Patient.where(id: ids)
```